# flutter_vpn not connecting on IOS Platform

Tags: flutter, networking, vpn

I have made a VPN Application on Flutter and it is working perfectly fine on Android but it does not connect on any iOS device.
I have used the flutter_vpn plugin and tried both the latest git commit of that plugin which included some updated and also tried the pub dev version of that package.

The issue is not being traced because I am not getting any error messages, the only message I get in console is Tunnel Started, What I think is the connection request Is being successfully made by the application but there is some parameters issue.

But the point is no one is having any issues with the plugin, so I don't think any additional parameters should be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed..
Needed to add the Encryption Algorithm and Integrity algorithm in the Swift library code Flutter_VPN.

```
p.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = NEVPNIKEv2EncryptionAlgorithm.algorithmAES256GCM
p.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = NEVPNIKEv2IntegrityAlgorithm.SHA384
p.ikeSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = NEVPNIKEv2DiffieHellmanGroup.group20
p.childSecurityAssociationParameters.encryptionAlgorithm = NEVPNIKEv2EncryptionAlgorithm.algorithmAES256GCM
p.childSecurityAssociationParameters.integrityAlgorithm = NEVPNIKEv2IntegrityAlgorithm.SHA384
p.childSecurityAssociationParameters.diffieHellmanGroup = NEVPNIKEv2DiffieHellmanGroup.group20
```